# how can i get the title of button on click in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to get the title of button when user click on any of button.How can I achieve this.I am trying to find the solution but not find the proper solution.
I come to know that

```
 IActionActivity
```

Is use to perform action on button click but i dont know how to implement that interface to get the title of button when user clicked

the image link is given below

```
  [BotAuthentication]
  public class MessagesController : ApiController
  {

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    { 
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {   
             Options(activity);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }




      private void Options(Activity reply)
      {
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        CardAction Button1 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Product is an interesting career choice.",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Product"

        };

        CardAction Button2 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Design is an interesting career choice.",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Design"

        };

        CardAction Button3 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Development is an interesting career choice.",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Development"
        };

        CardAction Button4 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Marketing is an interesting career choice.",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Marketing"
        };

        CardAction Button5 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Sales is an interesting career choice.",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Sales"
        };
        CardAction Button6 = new CardAction()
        {
            Value = "Administration is an interesting career choice.",
            Type = "postBack",
            Title = "Administration"
        };
        cardButtons.Add(Button1);
        cardButtons.Add(Button2);
        cardButtons.Add(Button3);
        cardButtons.Add(Button4);
        cardButtons.Add(Button5);
        cardButtons.Add(Button6);
        HeroCard jobCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Buttons = cardButtons
        };

        Attachment jobAttachment = jobCard.ToAttachment();
        reply.Attachments.Add(jobAttachment);
        reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;

    }
}
```

[image: conversation image from bot to user in bot emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once clicked you will get the `Value` of the button. `Activity.Text` should contain that value.

In any case, I'm seeing you are doing all the work in the controller. I would recommend using a `Dialog` instead.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered. Take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp there you will find a lot samples using dialogs